# Why doesn't work FILTER function in data validation list?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I want to use this formula in data validation list: (A7 cell)

```
=FILTER($A$1:$A$5;ISNUMBER(SEARCH(E1;$A$1:$A$5));"not found")
```

I got *"The source currently evaluates to an error."* message.

I need to drag this formula to get for E2, E3 etc.

[image: img]

Comment: *I need to drag this formula to get for E2, E3 etc.* - you want validation list drop downs in E2, E3? (PS pls include row header/columns in screenshot to make it easier to identify which cells you're referring to..)

Comment: you will need to put the formula in a helper column, then refer to that column in your data validation.  Most array formula, whether dynamic or not, do not work directly in data validation.

Comment: @ScottCraner - you beat me to it - was half way though composing below soln when your comment must've appeared :)

Answer (score 3):

*Unfortunately* there is no way to enter such a function directly within validation list dialogue / source.

*Fortunately* there are a couple of workarounds - I provide the simplest that does not require VB.

**Step 1)** Create single helper eqn: using filter function provided

```
=FILTER(B3:B6,--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(G2,B3:B6)))
```

[image: Helper function]

---

**Step 2)** Create named range referring to (1)

Create dynamic named range (Formulas-> Name Manager -> New) -- here: name:= 'LIST' and function/refers to:=

```
F3#
```

[image: Named range: 'LIST']

This will work given you must have Office 365 compatible version of Excel to use Filter function in first place…

*Note:
For those who have a similar enquiry {referencing range based upon function in validation list 'source') - but are not using Office 365 Excel version functions - you can proceed with same steps but modify Step 2 named range function as follows:*

```
F3:offset(F3, counta(F3:F1000)-1,0,1,1)
```

*making sure no 'obstructions' in column containing helper function - which is advisable for Office 365 users too.*

---

**Step 3)** Proceed with Validation List

Insert validation list by referencing new name in 2:

[image: Validation List with appropriate reference/source]

---

**Sample usage**

[image: Sample usage]

Voila!

---

Answer (score 0):

On
*Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2302 Build 16.0.16130.20332) 32-bit*
it still evaluates to an error for some reason, using F3#, however the offset one does work. Enterprise never seizes to disappoint!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35179125)